Nginx Reverse Proxy serving MP4/MKV Stuttering
I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy to serve HTTP video streams over HTTPS to avoid mixed content issues. However, I'm experiencing stuttering during video playback.
Problem:
The videos start playing but frequently pause at the same exact time during playback. Every time I try to watch a video, the stuttering happens at the exact same second.
This issue occurs with both MP4 and MKV files.
The stuttering does not occur when accessing the videos directly from the backend server; it only happens when accessed through the Nginx reverse proxy.
The stuttering does not occur when working with m3u8 files.
Here is my reverse proxy code:
server {
    gzip_static off;
    resolver 1.1.1.1;

    listen 25443 ssl;
    server_name my.proxy;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.proxy/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.proxy/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location /proxy/ {
        rewrite ^/proxy/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://example/$1;
        proxy_set_header User-Agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0";
        proxy_set_header Referer "example";
        proxy_set_header Host example;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        proxy_intercept_errors on; 

        error_page 301 302 = @handle_redirect;
    }

    location @handle_redirect {
        add_header X-Debug-Redirect-URL $upstream_http_location;

        set $new_url $upstream_http_location;

        if ($new_url = "") {
            return 500;
        }
        add_header X-Debug-New-URL $new_url;
        proxy_pass $new_url;

        proxy_set_header User-Agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;


        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";

    }
}

Do you guys know any ways I could Optimize this nginx configuration ?
Any ways to prevent stuttering in my videos ?
What I tried:
Disabled gzip compression by setting gzip_static off;.
Adjusted buffer sizes in Nginx:
Tweaked proxy_buffer_size, proxy_buffers, and proxy_busy_buffers_size.
Checked network latency:
Latency between the client and server is minimal.
